# Find all integers $a,b$ such that $\frac{b^{b} +b}{a\cdot b^2 +9}$ is an integer.

Tags: number-theory

> Find all integers $a,b$ such that $$\frac{b^{b} +b}{a\cdot b^2 +9}$$ is an integer.

I tried to separate out $a$, but it seems useless.

Comment: Can you tell me your method.? I have been trying long

Comment: $b=9,a=9^7$ is one solution. :)

Comment: $a=-7,-8,-10$ and $-11$ are solutions for $b=1$. $b^b+b$ is even for all $b>0$, and for those values of $a$ the denominator is $\pm1,\pm2$.

Comment: for $b = 2$, $a= -2,  -3, -4$  are possible

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think you are wrong. As vnd mentions $a=-3$ must also be in the solution set as with $b=2$ the result is an integer.

Comment: The $b$ for which it is possible, between $−20$ and $20$, are $\{−1,1,2,8,9,10,14,17,18,19\}$. I see no particular pattern to them. [Updated from previous wrong version, and derived using Mathematica.]

Comment: Can anyone suggest a method to generate such pairs manually without using computer programs?

Comment: Some more solutions with $0<a<1000$, $0<b<10000$. $a=2$, $b=10$; $a=6$, $b=14,104$; $a=9$ and lots of values of $b$, all multiple of $9$; $a=10$, $b=94$; $a=12$, b=8378; $a=108$, $b=90$; $a=162$, $b=5832$; $a=b=729$. All are multiples of $9$ except the cases $a=2$ and $a=6$. Other than that,  there is no clear pattern.

Comment: $b=10$ yields $a \in \{-909091, -1, 2\}$; $b=14$ yields $a=6$ only; $b=17$ yields $a=655166640308953$ only; $b=18$ yields $a=0$ or $a=60719765548297125888$. (These are all according to Mathematica 10.4.0.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens The problem with Mathematica, or any other software, is that they can not evaluate $b^b$ after $b=15$ because the number is too large for the computer architecture to represent. That's why computational solutions after $b=15$ should not be trusted.

Comment: @corbah It is simply false that $16^{16}$ is too big for Mathematica. It can represent $1,000,000!$ perfectly happily (a $5565709$ digit number), for instance; I doubt it has problems with a 20-digit one.

Comment: where did you get this problem?

Comment: I got this from AoPs

Comment: (2, 10) (6, 14) (6, 104) (9, 27) (9, 63) (9, 99) (9, 135) (9, 171) (9, 207) (9, 243) (9, 279) (9, 315) (9, 351) (9, 387) (9, 423) (9, 459) (9, 495) (9, 531) (9, 567) (9, 603) (9, 639) (9, 675) (9, 711) (9, 747) (9, 783) (9, 819) (9, 855) (9, 891) (9, 927) (9, 963) (9, 999) (10, 94) (108, 90)
I got these solutions by writing a python program below 1000

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ok, I think mathematica uses a different kind of algotithm to represent big integers.

Comment: @corbah It uses the GMP under the hood.

Comment: @corbah You can use `PowerMod` to compute $b^b$ modulo something.

Comment: Do we know if there are finite solutions? I feel that there are infinite of them.

Comment: It seems that there are infinitely many solutions: $a=9$, $b=9(4\,k-1)$, $k\in\mathbb N$. A "large" solution: $a=308$, $b=525\,902$.

Comment: I don't know if I'm correct but with @JulianAguirre I've managed to fix $a=9$ and then $b=9(4k-1)$ and have managed to reduce the expression to (Well, you actually can't call it reduced!):$$ \frac{9\,(4k-1)\,[(9(4k-1))^{2(18k-5)} + 1^2]}{(9(4k-1))^2 + 1^2} $$ I now feel that we can show that the numerator is divisible by denominator. You see the last term of numerator maybe is divisible by the denominator.

Comment: @AyanBiswas Are you sure that there isn't a typo in the question you've asked?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution:

- $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:a=0,b=18n$
- $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:a=0,b=18n+8$
- $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:a=0,b=18n+9$
- $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:a=9,b=36n+27$

Comment: I think that you meant $27 + 36n$ in the last case.

Comment: @Dhruv: Ooops, swapped them... Will correct, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: BTW, the first bullet and the third bullet can be reduced to $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:a=0,b=9n$.

Answer (score 0):

@AyanBiswas, I fixed $a=9$ and $b=9(4k-1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ works. Replacing them, I have managed to reduce it to:

$$ \frac{9\,(4k-1)\,[(9(4k-1))^{2(18k-5)} + 1^2]}{9[(9(4k-1))^2 + 1^2]}$$

You can easily cancel out the $9$'s. And I feel that the last term of the numerator is divisible by the last term of the denominator. I don't know how to show that but am sure it holds since I encountered that identity some time ago. I am pasting the [Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B(9(4k%E2%88%921))%5E(2(18k%E2%88%925))%2B1%5E2%5D%20%2F%20%5B(9(4k%E2%88%921))%5E2%2B1%5E2%5D%20for%20k%20%3D%201%20to%2010) which shows that it is true for the first $10\,k$. Hope you found that useful. So there are infinite solutions of the form $a=9$ and $b=9(4k-1)$ and it would be impossible  to find all the $b$'s. Hope you found that useful.

Please comment if you find any loopholes.